# How to merge two column into single column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table like this

```
id | firstname | lastname
--------------------------
1  | alex      | smith
2  | bush      | hall
3  | cris      | cruise
4  | diana     | krall
```

And i need two column are "firstname" and "lastname" will merge into a column is "name", and a comma will separated them, like this:

```
id | name
----------------
1  | alex, smith
2  | bush, hall
3  | cris, cruise
4  | diana, krall
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
SELECT id,
CONCAT(firstname,',',lastname) AS `name`
FROM table
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d4fc/1)

Also with `CONCAT_WS`

```
SELECT id,
CONCAT_WS(',',firstname,lastname) AS `name`
FROM table
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d4fc/2)

Comment: use text to ddl option :) in topbar of fiddle

Comment: Thanks M Khalid Junaid so much for helping me, it works great.